# forwarding mail loop in postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, openldap, dovecot, email-bounces

recently i configured my postfix server with dovecot, sasl and ldap according some tutorials. it works fine indeed but always when i receive email it disappears after literally 5 minutes, postfix says its forwarding mail loop, i was struggling for 2 weeks to find the bug but no idea where it could be, here is my postconf

```
    alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapalias_maps.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapgalias_maps_both.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapgalias_maps_member.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapgalias_maps_folder.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapgalias_maps_forward.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapualias_maps_folder.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapualias_maps_forward.cf
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps =
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter =
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
defer_transports =
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory =
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport =
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = , ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapmasquerade_domains.cf
masquerade_exceptions = root
message_size_limit = 0
message_strip_characters =
mydestination = $myhostname localhost $mydomain localhost.$mydomain mail.$mydomain ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapmydestination.cf
mydomain = photoshop-pro.de
myhostname = Miniserver.photoshop-pro.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.1.1.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/README_FILES
relay_clientcerts =
relayhost =
relocated_maps =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/samples
sender_canonical_maps =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = !gssapi, !external, static:all, digest-md5
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile =
smtp_tls_CApath =
smtp_tls_cert_file =
smtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
smtp_tls_key_file =
smtp_tls_per_site = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapsmtp_tls_per_site.cf
smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapaccess.cf
smtpd_tls_CAfile =
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/servercerts/servercert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/servercerts/serverkey.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
transport_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldaptransport_maps.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapvirtual_alias_domains.cf
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapuser_recipient_maps.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapgroup_recipient_maps.cf
```

and here is the log:

```
2016-02-28T16:12:48.875649+01:00 MiniServer postfix/cleanup[16116]: B3DD12087B: message-id=<DUB114-DS976D4F9115BCC33958644ECB90@phx.gbl>
2016-02-28T16:12:49.253707+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: B3DD12087B: from=<naumann5@hotmail.de>, size=1651, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2016-02-28T16:12:49.338794+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16111]: disconnect from dub004-omc3s24.hotmail.com[157.55.2.33]
2016-02-28T16:12:49.351540+01:00 MiniServer postfix/local[16117]: B3DD12087B: to=<master@photoshop-pro.de>, relay=local, delay=0.74, delays=0.64/0.06/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
2016-02-28T16:12:49.354372+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: B3DD12087B: removed
2016-02-28T16:20:23.113170+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16195]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:20:23.259277+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16195]: 3F0922087B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:20:23.295828+01:00 MiniServer postfix/cleanup[16198]: 3F0922087B: message-id=<DUB114-DS976D4F9115BCC33958644ECB90@phx.gbl>
2016-02-28T16:20:23.352397+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: 3F0922087B: from=<naumann5@hotmail.de>, size=2122, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2016-02-28T16:20:23.388043+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16195]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:20:23.489840+01:00 MiniServer postfix/local[16199]: 3F0922087B: to=<master@localhost.photoshop-pro.de>, orig_to=<master@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.32, delays=0.18/0.07/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
2016-02-28T16:20:23.492696+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: 3F0922087B: removed
2016-02-28T16:30:24.230226+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16268]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:30:24.370743+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16268]: 5A3FD2087B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:30:24.412993+01:00 MiniServer postfix/cleanup[16271]: 5A3FD2087B: message-id=<DUB114-DS976D4F9115BCC33958644ECB90@phx.gbl>
2016-02-28T16:30:24.465981+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: 5A3FD2087B: from=<naumann5@hotmail.de>, size=2596, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2016-02-28T16:30:24.489030+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtpd[16268]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
2016-02-28T16:30:24.978118+01:00 MiniServer postfix/local[16272]: 5A3FD2087B: to=<master@localhost.photoshop-pro.de>, orig_to=<master@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.68, delays=0.17/0.06/0/0.45, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail forwarding loop for master@localhost.photoshop-pro.de)
2016-02-28T16:30:24.999010+01:00 MiniServer postfix/cleanup[16271]: EF6A8208B6: message-id=<20160228153024.EF6A8208B6@Miniserver.photoshop-pro.de>
2016-02-28T16:30:25.023840+01:00 MiniServer postfix/bounce[16273]: 5A3FD2087B: sender non-delivery notification: EF6A8208B6
2016-02-28T16:30:25.026434+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: EF6A8208B6: from=<>, size=4655, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2016-02-28T16:30:25.043104+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: 5A3FD2087B: removed
2016-02-28T16:30:26.976391+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtp[16274]: EF6A8208B6: to=<naumann5@hotmail.de>, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72]:25, delay=2, delays=0.04/0.13/1.6/0.17, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72] said: 550 DY-001 (COL004-MC1F15) Unfortunately, messages from 178.203.24.21 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider. You can tell them that Hotmail does not relay dynamically-assigned IP ranges. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
2016-02-28T16:30:26.990938+01:00 MiniServer postfix/smtp[16274]: EF6A8208B6: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72] while sending RCPT TO
2016-02-28T16:30:26.994487+01:00 MiniServer postfix/qmgr[16079]: EF6A8208B6: removed
```

Comment: i found out that it could have something to do with e-mail transports, because as i configured the email server the first time i used yast, does anyone know where to find these options?

Comment: i also found out that if i just copy my own email message to inbox, it also says mail forwarding loop although i dont really receive the email i just copy from the draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, it was fetchmails fault. in the logs i could read that the email is fetched twice, it caused a problem with delivered-to header as well. thats why forwarding mail loop occured